# How to create unit test for a service class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have this service class code :

```
public class StaySearchManager
{
    private readonly IPriceGridRepo _priceGridRepo;

    public StaySearchManager(IPriceGridRepo priceGridRepo)
    {
        _priceGridRepo = priceGridRepo;
    }


    public async Task<IEnumerable<StaySearchResult>> Search(StaySearchParameter searchParameter)
    {
        if (!searchParameter.RoomIds.Any())
            return new StaySearchResult[0];
        PriceGrids[] grids = await _priceGridRepo.GetRoomPriceGrid(searchParameter.RoomIds);
        return grids.Select(g => g.TryCreateStay(searchParameter)).Where(s => s != null).ToList();           
    }
}
```

I'm able to create unit tests (using moq) for checking that:
- if there is no room ids then we'll return an empty result
- if there is some room ids, we'll call the repo with the good parameter

But how do I unit test the stay creation process ?

The first solution would be to create a IPriceGrid itnerface and then mock it, but it seems like an over-engeneering as this interface will be there only for the unit tests.

The second solution would be to do interation tests but it will be a duplicate of my unit tests on PriceGrid.

Any third solution ?

Comment: Can't you assert the return result of `Search` method ? If I understood the problem correctly.

Comment: @user3185569 yes I can because wit the mockRepo I can return the grids I desire (so deduce the stays/prices), this is the 2nd solution : all my test will be the same as the grid's unit test

Comment: You need to step away from micro testing (testing every single class) and get used to functional testing (testing collaboration between multiple classes). When you test `StaySearchManager`. you're indirectly testing the PriceGrids. (This holds in case you still have 100% coverage for all code execution paths)

Comment: Your `PriceGrid` class seems to violate SRP priciple and keeps you in that dilemma

Comment: @SirRufo There is only 1 method calculating prices based on two dates, can you post an answer where you elaborate a bit more ? SHould I create a PricigGridService ? But in the end I would have an anemic domain model I think

Comment: I have to correct myself a bit: Write unit tests for `PriceGrid.TryCreateStay` too so that you can rely on it in `StaySearchManager.Search`

Comment: @SirRufo ok then. This is already done, so for you there is no problem if my tests also run (so test) code from other components ?

Comment: No, all of your code will at least run code from other components (build-in, own, third-party). Just ensure all of them are well unit tested.

Comment: @remibourgarel `PriceGrids.TryCreateStay` can/should have it's own isolated unit tests. Once it has already been covered by tests then there is not much to be concerned about if it is in the above test case.

Comment: Can you add the listing for `PriceGrids` class? then I can provide an example of how i would test this.

Comment: @zaitsman this class already has all the unit tests it needs, I need to test a class that uses it

Comment: @remibourgarel you have tight coupling across the service and `PriceGrids`. I can't tell you how to test the service from the listing you are provided, it is insufficient.

Comment: you mean that I should create an interface for PriceGrids ? The TryCreateStay checks that there is a pricing period for the required dates and return the price of the stay. I don't want to overthink this and have 10 interfaces/implementations for 10 lines of executed code